# Jquery Auto change focused text box via button

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari

i am creating a system where there will be a pacific mobile view. From this you will be able to press one of 3 buttons and it will emulate a key press on a keyboard.
 Currently for the desktop version the focused box changes like this:

```
$('.today').keydown(function(e) {
    if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [69, 88, 191, 8, 40, 38]) === -1) { // 8 is backspace
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
$('.today').keyup(function(e) {
  if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [69, 88, 191, 8, 40, 38]) === -1) { // e, x, / respectively // don't print the character
    return false;
 }
  var self = $(this);
    var currentInput = self.data('number');
    var next = $(currentInput + 1);
    var previous = $(currentInput - 1);
    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var num = self.data('number') + 1;
    var nom = self.data('number') - 1;
    if(('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').length && keyCode === 40)
        $('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').focus()
    else if(('input.today[data-number="' + nom +'"]').length && keyCode === 38)
        $('input.today[data-number="' + nom +'"]').focus();
    else if(('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').length && self.val().length == self.attr('size')) {
       $('input.today[data-number="' + num +'"]').focus();
    }
});
```

For the buttons I have this piece of code:

```
$("button").click(function() {
     $(".today").focus();
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 47; // # Some key code value
    $("input").val(String.fromCharCode(e.which));
    $("input").trigger(e);
});
$('input').keypress(function(e){
   console.log('Yes keydown triggered. ' + e.which)
});
```

This fills the text box and it will change to next, but then when i press it will focus back to original... Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".today").focus();
```

suggests your using classes as the identifier, are your ID's unique?

Comment: Yes... The ID's are relative to a ID fetched from a DB.